# Is the returned object from an Objectbox query the same instance than the object in the ToMany<> relation?

Tags: objectbox

Thank you for your work on ObjectBox, I recently discovered it and it's amazing :)

Nevertheless, I have a problem I don't understand : I try to use Query, especially "find" and "findFirst" query. I try to get a particular object form its box in order to return it, and removed it form the Box.

My code is *(sorry, it is in french)* :

```
public DeplacementProvoque recupererEtRetirerDeplacementProvoque() {

    QueryBuilder<DeplacementProvoque> builder = DeplacementProvoque.deplacementProvoqueBox.query();
    builder.equal(DeplacementProvoque_.deplacementsProvoquesAssocieId, this.id)
           .equal(DeplacementProvoque_.estEnSursis, false);

    DeplacementProvoque deplacementProvoque = builder.build().findFirst();   // <<<< Use the Query

    listeDeplacementsProvoques.remove(deplacementProvoque);                  // <<<< Try to remove the object

    return deplacementProvoque;
}
```

I noticed the DeplacementProvoque got from the Query is the good object (same id as the expected one) but is not the same instance. So the remove() does not work.

I can get around this problem by iterating on the ToMany<> list to identify the good instance of the object, and remove it.

But I would know if this behavior is normal, or if I do something wrong ? Perhaps I incorrectly use the ToMany<> list, provoking this result ?

Thank you :)

Julien

PS : sorry for my probable english mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the headline question: no, you always get a new instance with the latest data when querying.

To answer your actual question: assuming that `listeDeplacementsProvoques` is a `ToMany` (you did not specify), you can use `ToMany.removeById(entityId)`.

Alternatively, you can implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` for your `DeplacementProvoque` entity. Then `ToMany.remove(entity)` will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Indeed, listeDeplacementsProvoques is a ToMany. I didn't noticed the removeById() method, I will use it :) 
Actually I also could implement hashCode() and equals(), I didn't think about this solution.